# illegal target for annotation issue

Tags: python

I ran the following query and received the following error:

```
Error on line 7:
    string== Name:first_name
    ^
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation.
```

What is the reason for the error?

```py
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    if first_name==" " and last_name==" ":
       string== Name:" "     
    elif first_name==" " and last_name !=" ":
       string== Name:last_name
    elif first_name !=" " and last_name ==" ":
       string== Name:first_name
    else: 
       string== Name:"first_name, last_name"
    return string 

    print(format_name("Ernest", "Hemingway"))
    print(format_name("", "Madonna"))
    print(format_name("Voltaire", ""))
    print(format_name("", ""))
```

Comment: Where you wrote `string== Name:" "` you meant `string: Name = " "`.  Use one equals for assignment, not two.

Comment: Also note that `if first_name==" "` is NOT the same thing as `if first_name==""`.  A string with one space is not equal to an empty string.  Even better is to say `if not first_name and not last_name:`.

Comment: What exactly is `Name`?  Assuming it's a valid type at all, it probably doesn't make sense to annotate a variable whose actual type is `str` as a `Name`, unless `Name` is specifically a type alias for `str` (and even then doing it in all those places is a bit weird -- if you were going to try to say that the strings returned by this function are `Name`s, you'd want to declare that in the function annotation, not inside the body of the function).

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `string== Name:" "   `, **what do you think this should mean**? Why? What part do you want to annotate, and how do you want it to be annotated? What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have made this more complicated than it needs to be. Remember that you only need to add an extra space if both names are given.  So:

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    if first_name and last_name:
        return first_name+" "+last_name
    else:
        return first_name+last_name

print(format_name("Ernest", "Hemingway"))
print(format_name("", "Madonna"))
print(format_name("Voltaire", ""))
print(format_name("", ""))
```